# How to calculate a modified moving average for a Python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

There are hundreds of examples on SO about moving average in pandas, however my case is slightly different, and I'm looking for some Pythonic solution:

Requirements:
Given a window, say 5, I'd like to calculate a modified moving average for coumn `target` and dump the result in a new column, say, `MA`:

For index from 0~3 (first four), use SUM(0~index of `target`) / (index + 1);

For index >= window - 1 (4 in this case), it's a normal MA(5). I'm assuming that MA(5) starts from 5th element.

What I tried:

First I know that I can use:

```
df[maname] = df.rolling(window=win)[target].mean()
```

to calculate a normal MA(win) and dump into column `maname`.

Then I tried a few other methods but none of them works:

```
df[maname] = df[target][:df.index + 1].sum() / (df.index + 1) if df.index < win else df.rolling(window=win)[target].mean()
```

This gives an error and I realized that this is ambiguous in `pandas`.

Next one:

```
df[maname] = 0
df[maname][df.index<=win] = df[target][:df.index + 1].sum() / (df.index + 1)
df[maname][df.index>win] = df.rolling(window=win)[target].mean()
```

Error:

> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexer

Next try:

I'm out of tricks so I decide to use the normal C++ method: loop through index (this algorithm is actually different from the moving average, but this is not my problem for now)

```
    for idx in df.index:
        loop = 0
        while loop <= idx:
            df[maname].iloc[idx] = df[maname].iloc[idx] + df[target].iloc[loop]
            loop = loop + 1

        if idx < win:
            df[maname].iloc[idx] = df[maname].iloc[idx] / (idx + 1)
        else:
            df[maname].iloc[idx] = df[maname].iloc[idx] / win
```

But surprisingly, all values of my new column is zero! I have no idea what's the problem. **Edit** I was reminded by a redittor that integers are immutable so I know why it's all zero, also this is very low efficient.

Most recent try:

I even tried to hard-code a lot of things but this seems to be beyond my capability...

```
for idx in range(0, 23):
    loop = 0
    while loop <= idx:
        dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] = dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] + 5
        loop = loop + 1

    if idx < 5:
        dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] = dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] / (idx + 1)

    else:
        dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] = dfToWrite.at[idx, 'MA'] / 5
```

Error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Anyway, I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to do this, and **in general if there is an elegant way to apply calculated values by a function of indices** (e.g. if func_index(index) < 1,000, value should be func_value(another column * 10))

Comment: Seems an easy way to get what you want is just to do two passes, using temporary columns. Make a windowed average of the index column, and the normal moving average column, and add them together however you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with stock data, you can give [stockstats](https://github.com/jealous/stockstats) a try.
Here is sample code:

```
stock = StockDataFrame.retype(pd.read_csv('stock.csv'))
stock['close_5_sma']
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark I'm not using stock data, but I assume that I can still use this functionality? I'll take a look, thank you!

Comment: You can! @NicholasHumphrey  You just need setting a column name as "close"